# Month and Quarter reputation tab borked?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

When I went to look at the [Quarter reputation tab](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter) I noticed I'm number 1 in the stats and the same goes for the [month](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) but 
as I know I'm vastly inferior to [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind?tab=reputation) **0:-)** I'm suspecting something is borked in a query somewhere.

Should I take this to meta.se or <s>[does shog9 trawl here too](https://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/18692/3)</s> **;-)** do the StackExchange Developers read this meta too if tagged as a bug???

Comment: I don't understand. What makes you think there's an issue? This month and this week simply means today since it's the first of the month and a Monday. You've gotten 41 points today and Rinzwind's gotten 20. Everything seems fine. And yes, SE employees see the bug tag on child metas. I doubt they'll appreciate the suggestion that they are trolls though.

Comment: @shog9 See above.  People getting worried I've offended you. Did that comment make you smile or make you frown?  (If the latter: I was trying to make you smile, hence the **;-)** )

Comment: @terdon *I'm an idiot:* Makes perfect sense now.  I'm just used for a "Month" to be a "rolling month* i.e. Last 30 days.

Comment: Ah not in this case, yeah.

Comment: Made me curious as to if you meant "trawl"

Comment: Thanks Shog9!  [Edited](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/18692/revisions) to make it more humourous.  **0:-)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the beginning of a period--whether it be a week, month, or quarter--the stats for that period go back to zero, because they applied to the previous period, which has just ended. This is probably the only reasonable way those stats could be displayed, but I've found it confusing as well, because when one week, month, or quarter is considered to end is sort of an arbitrary cultural fact.

As [terdon said](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18692/month-and-quarter-reputation-tab-borked#comment39938_18692):

> This month and this week simply means today since it's the first of the month and a Monday. You've gotten 41 points today and Rinzwind's gotten 20. Everything seems fine.

**Note also that you observed this on the first day of July, which is the beginning of the third quarter of the year.** So all three periods happened to have restarted anew at that time.

As [you mentioned](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18692/month-and-quarter-reputation-tab-borked#comment39940_18692), the month shown there is not a rolling month, even though the concept of a rolling period of is intuitive and often useful. This is analogous, and similarly confusing, to the distinction between the English phrases "within the hour" and "within an hour."