# Why does my week rank show -483?

Tags: support, reputation

When I visit https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/week/askubuntu I see this:

[image: Loss of reputation?]

However, I don't see that rep loss in my [Ask Ubuntu profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose?tab=reputation)

[image: Rep at Ask Ubuntu]

(The recent rep loss was only ~65 and others were affected more or less across Stack Exchange.)

How to reconcile the two?

I've used the bug tag. I hope that's appropriate.

Related: [Month and Quarter reputation tab borked?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18692/month-and-quarter-reputation-tab-borked)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The -483 isn't an amount of reputation, it's what your change in rank was.

For example, if I'm in 3rd place one week and drop to 10th, I've dropped seven slots, so my change is -7. If I do better the following week and get to 2nd place, the change is +8.

In your case, you were in 23rd place the week prior but you're now in 506th place, so the change was -483 (483+23=506).

[image: DK Bose rank for week of Jun 23-29 - 23rd place]

You can see your rank the prior week by clicking "prev week" in the blue box in the upper right corner that has the dates.

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug, that's the '**change**' in rank (with respect to last week's rank).

Comment: Thanks! Fabby made me jumpy ;)